# Remove equal characters from two python strings

Tags: python, string, list

I am writing a Python code to remove equal same characters from two strings which lies on the same indices. For example `remove_same('ABCDE', 'ACBDE')` should make both arguments as BC and CB. I know that string is immutable here so I have converted them to list. I am getting an out of index error.

```
def remove_same(l_string, r_string):
    l_list = list(l_string)
    r_list = list(r_string)
    i = 0
    while i != len(l_list):
        print(f'in {i} length is {len(l_list)}')
        while l_list[i] == r_list[i]:
            l_list.pop(i)
            r_list.pop(i)
        if i == len(l_list) - 1:
            break
        if i != len(l_list):
            i += 1

    return l_list[0] == r_list[0]
```

Comment: You have a `while l_list[i] == r_list[i]` loop inside your other while-loop, and you're not checking the bounds of `i` inside the inner loop.

Comment: `while i != len(l_list) and l_list[i] == r_list[i]` Is this so?

Comment: Please provide  the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  In particular, post the *entire* error message, including trace-back.  Also trace (print out) the offending values just before the failure point.  Work backward to determine how those values went out of range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid using a while loop in that case, I think this is a better and more clear solution:

```
def remove_same(s1, s2):
    l1 = list(s1)
    l2 = list(s2)
    out1 = []
    out2 = []
    for c1, c2 in zip(l1, l2):
        if c1 != c2:
            out1.append(c1)
            out2.append(c2)
            
    s1_out = "".join(out1)
    s2_out = "".join(out2)
    
    print(s1_out)
    print(s2_out)
```

It could be shortened using some list comprehensions but I was trying to be as explicit as possible

Comment: You don't need to convert `s1` and `s2` to lists if you're doing it this way.

Answer (score 1):

I feel this could be a problem.

```py
while l_list[i] == r_list[i]:
            l_list.pop(i)
            r_list.pop(i)
```

This could reduce size of list and it can go below `i`.

Do a dry run on this, if l_list = ["a"] and r_list = ["a"].

Answer (score 1):

It is in general not a good idea to modify a list in a loop. Here is a cleaner, more Pythonic solution. The two strings are zipped and processed in parallel. Each pair of equal characters is discarded, and the remaining characters are arranged into new strings.

```
a = 'ABCDE'
b = 'ACFDE'

def remove_same(s1, s2):
    return ["".join(s) for s
            in zip(*[(x,y) for x,y in zip(s1,s2) if x!=y])]

remove_same(a, b)
#['BC', 'CF']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```py
def remove_same(l_string, r_string):
    # if either string is empty, return False
    if not l_string or not r_string:
        return False
    l_list = list(l_string)
    r_list = list(r_string)
    limit = min(len(l_list), len(r_list))
    i = 0
    while i < limit:
        if l_list[i] == r_list[i]:
            l_list.pop(i)
            r_list.pop(i)
            limit -= 1
        else:
            i += 1

    return l_list[0] == r_list[0]


print(remove_same('ABCDE', 'ACBDE'))
```

Output:

```
False
```